# DOM element doesn't display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new in Javascript and I am trying to test following code

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="jquery/jquery.min.js">
  </head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="Click button">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('input')[0].on('click',function(){
      alert('button clicked');
    });  
   });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

but when i open this html file in browser the button doesn't display

Comment: Close `<script>` block

Comment: And fix `$('input')[0].on()`. It's not related to your current problem, but it should be `$('input').eq(0).on()` instead.

Comment: DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/dwL8k/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Script tags require a closing tag, which you've omitted:

```
<script src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
                                   ^ close
```

By leaving it open, the browser is treating everything after the script tag as the script content.

Also your `$('input')[0]` isn't right. That is getting the DOM element of the input, which has no jQuery wrapper and no `.on()` function. If you are trying to match just the first input then:

```
$('input').first().on('click',function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems

1. Script block must be closed which you missed.
2. Use `$('input')` instead of `$('input')[0]`, When you use `$('input')[0]` you get DOM element which doesn't have click method.

Use

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="Click button">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('input').on('click',function(){
      alert('button clicked');
    });  
   });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid these kind of confusions, try to separate like below,

In HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
 <body>
   <input type="button" value="Click button">
 </body>
</html>
```

In main.js

`$(function(){
    $('input').on('click',function(){
      alert('button clicked');
    });

   });`

For [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8bXTt/)

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `<!DOCTYPE html>` is better when you continue developing.